# Flutter fl_chart: Is there a way to insert a slider or manage the tap from outside the graph?

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

Is there a way to insert a slider or manage the tap from outside the graph?

Something like this:

[image]

Or is there a way to make the LineTouchData always visible (even before tapping on the graph)?